# Searching a document library doesnt seem to work

Tags: search, sharepoint-on-prem

On a site i got a Document Library,  having search field; whatever i type there documents are not searched through.

Editing the page added a search control.
Still no success

I want it to find a document that i've just uploaded, based on some of the words that are in that document.

Answer (score 1):

Search requires that your content first be indexed by the crawler.  If you just uploaded the document, odds are very good it hasn't been indexed yet and therefore won't appear in search results.

Do you know how often your crawl runs? If you're running continuous crawls, you should expect to see your document in the search results within about 15 minutes.  Ask your farm administrator what the crawl schedules look like.

Comment: I've triggered the crawler through admin desktop, but i think this is related to the fact that this is standaard version of sharepoint 2013-on-prem and not enterprice version,

Comment: If you don't have continuous crawl enabled, then it would get picked up by the incremental crawl if configured, otherwise whenever your full crawl is configured.

Comment: I'm assuming you've triggered the crawler through the search service application in Central Admin? Have you checked the crawl log, to see if it's returning any errors? That should be your first check.

Comment: Only enterprice version of sharepoint does allow searching on document content.